# Search syntax for the sender of *.MSG emails saved in SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, syntax

What is the correct search syntax to find *.msg emails that have been **sent** by e.g. Alice?

When I use one of the below search queries in the SharePoint search box at the top of the [SharePoint library page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mssxz.png) (or in the [company-global SharePoint page](https://i.imgur.com/8WJxV22.png)), it seems that all emails that were **uploaded** to SharePoint by Alice are found, even if they were sent e.g. by Bob and not by Alice.

```
filetype:msg recipient:charlie sender:alice 
filetype:msg recipient:charlie author:alice 
filetype:msg recipient:charlie from:alice
```

What syntax can be used to find only emails that actually were **sent** by Alice?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a look at the search schema. I do not expect this to work.

The filetype managed property is present but the others like recipient and sender are not present.
author is present as managed properties but seems to use only Office related crawled properties.
From is present in our tenants because we manually added this managed properties to allow users to use Outlook-like searches in SharePoint. We use apps that allowing extraction of email metadata during uploading or from existing emails in SharePoint. This then allows for Outlook-like searches in SharePoint:
from:paul subject:invoice sender:microsoft

Indexing emails in SharePoint has several limitations. Email metadata is not extract, the contents of email attachments are not indexed (only the name of the attachment), ...

Summary:
If you want to search for email metadata like sender:alice you will need to

1. Create a content type for emails with the email metadata fields like sent date, subject, sender, ...
   (or add these email columns to the default Document content type)
2. Configure the managed properties in the search schema to allow searching against the crawled properties.
3. Implement solutions to extract the email metadata since metadata is not automatically extracted from emails in SharePoint. There are 2 approaches:
   a. some tools (Outlook add-ins or SharePoint apps) extract the metadata values during uploading and capture the values into SharePoint columns.
   b. there are also tools/script that will extract email metadata from emails present in SharePoint. For example, after emails have been migrated from a different system.

Some organisations combine the 2 to be 100% sure email metadata is extracted from all emails.

Comment: Thanks, however the recipient:charlie part seems to be working fine. So why is there nothing like sender:xyz that works?

Comment: Do you have managed properties defined for recipient, sender, author and from?
Another test: add a email containing the word charlie in the body (not as recipient): does that email surface on the search result list?

Comment: I don't know about managed properties, that's probably something to discuss with IT? And I just realized that whatever adressee property I use, it always searches the entire mail body for it, like for example this search "filetype:msg recipient:probably from:authorization" seems to find pretty much the same as this one: "filetype:msg probably authorization"

Comment: Also, I thought that search operators like "before:2015" would work, but they don't. Do I really have to use things like "created<2015-01-01" all the time for this? OTOH, "modified<2015-01-01" doesn't seem to work either. Is there a comprehensive list somewhere how to do advanced search in SharePoint, but for users and not for programmers?

Comment: Users do not access to the page with the search schema. Contact IT, do not discuss by email but plan a session. This way you can get clear which managed properties are available.
I do not expect that the managed properties you are interested in are present. It requires special apps / tools to extract the email metadata from emails in SharePoint. For example Harmon.ie (Outlook plug-in), Colligo, ... and there are browser-based solutions (SLIM Email Manager) or stand-alone systems like BulkMetadataManager)

Comment: I mean just standard advanced search like shown in the below link. There must be an official, somewhat more complete source for that by Microsoft somewhere? https://www.sharepointeurope.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/How-to-Search-in-SharePoint-1.png

Comment: Understanding KQL is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference
but you sometimes need to combine it with the managed properties that are avialable in your own tenant.

Comment: Thanks -- in the meantime, I realized that not even things like "author:Alice" work in our SharePoint, no matter if I start the search from the Office 365 start page, from a SharePoint library, from the company start page, or from the provided SharePoint 
Advanced Search page. It always seems to search for full text containing "Alice", including finding documents that do not even contain "Alice" anywhere but that have been only uploaded by Alice. That can't be true, can it? Is SharePoint Search really that bad by default?

Comment: This situation doesn't seem to have changed much in the last 15 years, from the perspective of the end user, has it...?
https://www.computerworld.com/article/2348676/what-were-they-thinking---unraveling-the-mysteries-of-sharepoint-search--created-by.html

Comment: Indeed. Plenty of room for improvement of the documentation. I normally end up with multiples attempts to construct complex search queries like list all document modified between date1 and date2 in a certain folder that exceed a certain size and having a certain managed property.